# The type bool in not compatible with type Constraints.constraint

Tags: f#

I have made the following class:

```
type numbers(Roman:string, CommonNumber:string)=
          member this.RomanNumber=Roman
          member this.ExpectedNumber=CommonNumber

          member this.MakeComparision()=
                           string (convert(Roman))= CommonNumber
```

and then i tried to run the following test on it:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"..\packages\NUnit.2.6.4\lib\nunit.framework.dll"
#r @"..\packages\FsUnit.1.4.0.0\lib\net45\FsUnit.NUnit.dll"
#endif


    open NUnit.Framework
    open FsUnit


[<TestFixture>]

    type ``Given a Roman number ``()=
         let setNumbers=new numbers("XCIX","99")


         [<Test>]

         member this.
               ``Whether the right convert for this number must be exist``()=
                 setNumbers.MakeComparision() |> should be true
```

In the last line `setNumbers.MakeComparision() |> should be true`, on word `true`, i have the following erorr:

```
The type bool in not compatible with type Constraints.constraint
```

and i cannot handle it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh that is a nasty one (fell for it often)

you either need to use `equal` with the `true` *value*:

```
member this.
       ``Whether the right convert for this number must be exist``()=
         setNumbers.MakeComparision() 
         |> should equal true
```

or you need to use the `True` *constraint* with `be`:

```
member this.
       ``Whether the right convert for this number must be exist``()=
         setNumbers.MakeComparision() 
         |> should be True
```

see the [documentation](https://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/)